# Double sequences and series double.

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I would like a good reference devoted exclusively to double sequences and series double. At the moment I have only this reference in [google](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=EdBUAAAAYAAJ&q=double%20series%20books&dq=double%20series%20books&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=jhDnULjqIYfc8ATH1oBQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This PDF](http://www.iugaza.edu.ps/ar/periodical/articles/volume%2014-%20Issue%201%20-studies%20-16.pdf) is a very good start.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I already knew this PDF. 've Seen but also other notes. Therefore I am interested in references type Handbooks.